# ReactNative AsyncStorage methods not responding

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

my problem is in the title.

```
// Using AsyncStorage to add product to storage
const onProductAddButtonPress = (): void => {
  console.log('1');
  () => AppStorage.getShoppingCart([]).then(shoppingCart => {
    console.log('2');
    shoppingCart.push(new ShoppingCartProduct(
      selectedProduct.id,
      selectedProduct.name,
      selectedProduct.images,
      selectedProduct.price,
      productAmount
    ));
    AppStorage.setShoppingCart(shoppingCart);
  }).catch(error => console.log(error));
  setVisible(false)
};
```

I added different console logs to see what is going on. Console log '1' is getting displayed, but neither '2' nor 'error'.

```
// getShoppingCart
static getShoppingCart = (fallback?: Array<ShoppingCartProduct>): Promise<Array<ShoppingCartProduct>> => {
  return AsyncStorage.getItem(SHOPPINGCART_KEY).then((shoppingCart: string) => {
    return JSON.parse(shoppingCart) || fallback;
  });
};
```

```
// setShoppingCart
static setShoppingCart = (shoppingCart: Array<ShoppingCartProduct>): Promise<void> => {
  return AsyncStorage.setItem(SHOPPINGCART_KEY, JSON.stringify(shoppingCart));
}
```

I dont know what could be wrong, maybe its working as there is no error in catch but the console log '2' isnt showing anything either.

Comment: Did you try to remove the `() =>` from `() => AppStorage.getShoppingCart([])...` ? I'm not sure I understand why you wrote it like that

Comment: I removed it and it works!! Thanks